# Is there anyone who successfully installed first flutter demo_app on Mac recently?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have tried many times to install for my Mac OS with instruction official web-site step by step but I got problem after command flutter create my_app. 
What I got from my terminal:

Got TLS error trying to find cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org
and so on ....

I deleted several times again installed not success, I could not find exact answer for that anywhere(only find for windows and linux), so i decided to ask here, please guys who installed o Mac share with me, please. 
If you help me you will prolong my life.
Thank you in advance guys

Comment: Can you try to run this command and check, DART_VM_OPTIONS=--root-certs-file=some_file flutter packages get

Comment: I did on terminal and I got : Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter.